# Google Chat Rest API

Tags: php, api, rest, google-chat

I have not been able to find any documentation to authenticate and use the Google Chat API using a simple REST request.
I have scoured the Google official documentation and it immediately states we must use Python.
As far as I know REST is simply HTTP and JSON.

The [official documention](https://developers.google.com/chat/api/guides/libraries#php) link refers examples to Google Drive and Google Plus (deprecated). I am not a novice at Google APIs and have successfully programmed for Drive, Sheets, Calendar and Maps. This Chat is where I am requesting help

Any help / further documentation links is all I ask !!!

I am asking for documentation/examples of REST request (with auth) and methods and parameters

I am programming in PHP.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chat/api/guides/auth

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure which documentation you are referring to, but I haven't come across any documentation that explicitly states that we must use Python. It's possible that there is a lack of example code for other languages. However, Google has developed client libraries for various popular languages. For PHP, you can utilize the [google-api-php-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client#authentication-with-oauth) library, which is mentioned in their [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/chat/api/guides/libraries#php).

Here the example code to send a message. I successfully tried it using my credential and chat space.

```
    $client = new Client();
    $client->setAuthConfig('/path/to/client_credentials.json');
    $client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chat.bot');
    $chat = new Google\Service\HangoutsChat($client);
    $message = new \Google\Service\HangoutsChat\Message();
    $message->setText("This is example message");
    $createMessage = $chat->spaces_messages->create('spaces/AAAAqFtzdps',$message);
```

You can check the available class/methods of google chat [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client-services/tree/main/src/HangoutsChat)

Comment: I read that and exactly my point, the official documention link refers examples to Google Drive and Google Plus (deprecated). I am not a novice at Google APIs and have successfully programmed for Drive, Sheets, Calendar and Maps. This Chat is where I am requesting help

Comment: Google drive is just an example, you can use other service also like Chat, Books, and other. I will provide you an example for chat.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I am asking for, REST request (with auth) and documentation on methods and parameters

Comment: thanks @Muhammad Dyas Yaskur I will try it out - is this for the current Chat App and not old Hangouts - I ask as I see  $client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chat.bot');
    $chat = new Google\Service\HangoutsChat($client);

Comment: @Datadimension old hangout is upgraded to current chat app. So this is for current chat app. BTW, If you are interested for your reference, I also built couple of google chat apps using nodejs: https://github.com/dyaskur/google-chat-poll . I also have a plan to build app using PHP and other languages in the future.

Comment: Sounds like great work. I think lacking particularly with Google is that they state they use REST and then all the examples, much of their docs start with PREREQUITES - Python ????? I would have thought REST would be their basis to work from but oh well. A pure REST API for all their APIs would be magnificent.....  :)

Comment: It's just not feasible to provide reference docs for every API in every language. They don't even write the client libraries, it's all generated code. For all but the prestige-tier Google services you're going to need to get cozy with the API docs and reading the client library source.

Comment: Google\Service\Exception
{ "error": { "code": 403, "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.", "errors": [ { "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.", "domain": "global", "reason": "forbidden" } ], "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED" } }